# Memory size explosion in Java after loading small csv file

Tags: java, csv, data-science

I loaded a 251Mb CSV file into java and I am now told that the memory usage from this is 6.8Gb.

I am using a map to keep all the rows and each row is kept in an object with a string, long and another map for other strings, because there is some variability to how many strings there may be in it.

How did the memory explode?

Comment: You can use various JVM profilers to identify where the memory has gone.  VisualVM (I believe) is free and comes with old versions of the JDK.  I don't know if it's been updated for the latest java versions (depending on what you're using).  But JProfiler and YourKit are out there too (although I believe they're paid for commercial use).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5865024/putting-csv-file-into-memory